# Regex to keep specified CSS rules

Tags: css, regex

Spent several hours on this and done a lot of searching and am getting nowhere. Looking for help from the RegEx guru's. I'm looking for a RegEx that can remove all CSS style rules except ones I specify.  For instance, take the following example input:

```
<p style="font-size:10px">Text.</p>
<p><span style="font-size:12px; text-transform:uppercase">More text</span></p>
<p><span style="text-decoration:line-through; text-transform:uppercase;">Even more</span></p>
```

I'm looking for this output:

```
<p>Text.</p>
<p><span style="text-transform:uppercase">More text</span></p>
<p><span style="text-decoration:line-through; text-transform:uppercase;">Even more</span></p>
```

So only keep `text-transform:uppercase` and `text-decoration:underline`.  If this needs to be broken up in a couple RegExes that's fine.  i.e. the first one leaves empty `style=""` tags I can remove those after.  The key here is I want to specify the rules to keep, not all the possible rules to remove.

Thanks for any help

Update:
The closest I've come is this:

```
style=".*?(text-decoration:line-through|text-transform:uppercase)*.*?"
```

and replacing with $1.  The problem is it's not capturing the rules I want to keep when I add the * after the capture group.

Comment: Why would you want to use regex for this?

Comment: Because I'm having to use a 3rd party conversion tool for a project and the only way to makes alterations like this is via RegEx.  Otherwise, yes I would use some sort of CSS parser.

Comment: Just pass the intermediary result through Phantomjs or something similar.

Comment: That would add an additional step to this process which will need to be repeated regularly and often.  This seems entirely doable with RegEx, I'm just not familiar enough.  It's worth noting that the CSS generated by this 3rd party software is very clean and consistent, which tends to be the issue when trying to parse CSS manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think a black list would be easier than a white list here. I'd give this a shot before I dig too deep into it.

```
/(font-size|color):[^;]+(; |)?/g
```

Here was my test:

```
var test = 'style="font-size:12px; color:red; background:blue; color:blue"'

// style="background:blue; "
test.replace(/(font-size|color):[^;]+(; |)?/g, '');
```

Edited it after you said the CSS is consistent.

Comment: You are correct, a blacklist would be significantly easier.  However, there's no telling how many different CSS rules could be included that I don't want.  What I do know for sure is I only want these 2 to remain.  Thanks for the input, though.  If I can't come up with a decent whitelist this will probably be the next best thing.

Comment: I've confirmed that your regex works with the markup generated by the software and it's cleaner than the blacklisting method I came up with yesterday.  But I'd still like to try for a whitelist method.

Answer (score 0):

Well it doesn't look like I'm going to get a whitelist so I've went ahead with the blacklist.  Upon further testing Bill's had an issue which caused it to match more than just the CSS.  So I've come up with the following that seems to be working well, largely based on Bill's idea so thanks to him for posting.

```
(font-size|color):.*?(;|(?="))
```

I'm still open to a whitelist solution should anyone come up with one.